# Mathquill and HTML tags

Tags: html, mathquill

I am using mathquill as:

```
<span class="mathquill-embedded-latex">'\text{Is }x^3+1\text{a linear equation? <br/> If true, mark Yes.}'</span>
```

But, how to ensure that html tags are getting rendered. Because when I display the above I get something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS1kf.png

Which means that the html tags aren't rendering. What can I do to render html tags?

Comment: `something like this` - like what? there is no screenshot.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot. I can see it too. To put it in words: the html tags aren't rendering and it is just displaying everything in one line. 

Is x3+1 a linear equation? If true, mark Yes.

Comment: _\*confused*_ for some reason screenshot has `display: none` inline style =\

Answer (score 0):

Try output as latex only equation:

```
<span>Is <span class="mathquill-embedded-latex">'x^3+1'</span> a linear equation? <br/> If true, mark Yes.</span>
```

Comment: The string is stored in database as this:
\text{Is }x^3+1\text{a linear equation? <br/> If true, mark Yes.}

I will have to extract the text part separately i guess.

Comment: Have you tried using `\newline` or ``\\`` instead of `<br />`: `\text{Is }x^3+1\text{a linear equation?}\newline\text{If true, mark Yes.}` ? That would require to filter questions and replace regex `\s*<br\s*/>\s*` with `}\newline\text{`

Comment: No doesn't work. I think mathquill just removes any html tags as I can't see it being rendered on the page anywhere.

The only solution I can think of is to display formula or equation separately enclosed in mathquill tag.

Comment: looked at mathquill issues tracker - `\newline` and ``\\`` support marked with `Maybe in far far far future`... =\ I suppose, mundane `replace("<br />", "\n")` also wouldn't work...